# When I try to use `\splitfrac` or `\splitdfrac` in math section, I get an additional 0 or 1 in the result

Tags: mathtools

```
\begin{flalign*}
    z&=\frac{\splitfrac{ab+cd+ef+gh+ij}{+kl+mn+op+qr}}{y}\\
    z&=\frac{\splitdfrac{ab+cd+ef+gh+ij}{+kl+mn+op+qr}}{y}
\end{flalign*}
```

It can be seen from the figure below there is an additional term of 1 and 0 in the second line of split equation. I wonder why ? How can i rectify it ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! We need more code. Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Embedded in a typical MWE, not only your code does not exhibit the problem, it also yields different character sizes than those in your picture.

Comment: By the way, `flalign*` does the same as `align*`, with your input.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem under an up-to-date TeX Live 2017 ([file list](https://pastebin.com/T4EDtDzv) when loading only [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) in the `article` class).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem under an up-to-date 64-bit MikTeX.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem using IEEE template.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    z&=\frac{\splitfrac{ab+cd+ef+gh+ij}{+kl+mn+op+qr}}{y}\\
    z&=\frac{\splitdfrac{ab+cd+ef+gh+ij}{+kl+mn+op+qr}}{y}
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

in a one year old texlive installation.