# \splitfrac producing extra '1' characters

Tags: mathtools

I am having the exact same problem as this [(closed) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375008/when-i-try-to-use-splitfrac-or-splitdfrac-in-math-section-i-get-an-additi) - but I have ideas as to what might be causing the problem in my case

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}_{x}=\frac{\splitfrac{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{m}}{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}}}{\splitfrac{\Pr(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x))^{m}}{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

When I run the code as it is above, I get my desired output:
[image]

However, when I run it with the entire preamble that I am using for a longer document, I get extra "1" characters

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,apacite,graphicx, verbatim,upref,paralist,indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{breqn}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}_{x}=\frac{\splitfrac{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{m}}{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}}}{\splitfrac{\Pr(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x))^{m}}{\Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0, \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am suspecting that there is some "contamination" from other packages in the preamble that are producing these unwanted "1" characters. Is there anything I can do to remove these unwanted "1"s? Is there a way I can do this without removing other packages from the preamble, as this may affect other formulae that I have in the document.

Edit:
I suspect it is this line in the preamble that is causing the "1" to appear:

```
    \usepackage{breqn}
```

When I remove it from the preamble, the 1's disappear. Is there a way to remove the 1's without removing this line from the preamble?

Comment: Related: [How can I split and align this series of equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160830/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A really minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\[
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{A}{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

that typesets

[image]

whereas it typesets as expected if `breqn` is changed into `amsmath`. Note that `\splitfrac` is just a thin layer around `\genfrac`.

Oh, wait! How does the minimal example compile? Isn't `\genfrac` defined by `amsmath` that isn't loaded? Yes, that's true. Besides other damages, `breqn` seizes the initiative to define (or redefine) `\genfrac`. But it does it wrong. The definition is in `mathstyle.sty`

```
 145   │ \DeclareRobustCommand\genfrac[6]{%
 146   │   {#1\fracstyle
 147   │     {\begingroup #5\endgroup
 148   │       \csname @@\ifx\maxdimen#4\maxdimen over\else above\fi
 149   │         \if @#2@\else withdelims\fi\endcsname #2#3#4\relax
 150   │      #6}%
 151   │   }%
 152   │ }
```

and `#2#3#4\relax` should be `#2#3\relax`. The modified macro gives the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\genfrac}{#4\relax}{\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{A}{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

Without `regexpatch`, your document should look as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\genfrac[6]{%
  {#1\fracstyle
  {\begingroup #5\endgroup
     \csname @@\ifx\maxdimen#4\maxdimen over\else above\fi
     \if @#2@\else withdelims\fi\endcsname #2#3\relax
     #6}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_{x}=
  \frac{
    \splitfrac{
      \Pr\left(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1,
      \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{m}
    }{
      \Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=1,
      \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}
    }
  }{
    \splitfrac{
      \Pr(\tau_{i}\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0,
      \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x))^{m}
    }{
      \Pr\left(\tau_{i}\not\in[x, x+\delta)|\omega_{x+\delta}=0,
      \tau_{i}\not\in [x-\delta, x)\right)^{k-m-1}
    }
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bug report filed: https://github.com/wspr/breqn/issues/25